# MVC5 + Autofac: DbContext is being reused

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I have my context registered like so:

```
 internal class DbContextModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(ctx => new CRTechEntities()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Controllers are registered as such:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In one of repositories, I ask for it in the ctor, however it is not a new context..

```
 if(_context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any())
    _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().Each(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

is causing all sorts of issues, and I don't understand why the context is not a new one. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create new instance on each request use

`InstancePerDependency` instead of `InstancePerLifetimeScope`

`InstancePerLifetimeScope` creates one instance for each scope, if you don't create scope Autofac creates default scope, and use it everywhere

Also please note, that if you are in asp.net project, better practice to use one instance for each request `InstancePerRequest`

For more about [check here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-dependency)

Comment: When I do this, I get a new error saying that I can't have multiple changetracker instances pointed at the same entity :/ (That was the first thing I tried)

Comment: I guess because you are tracking changes of entity using difference instances of datacontext... try to call save changes you finish in one place... actually it would be better if you can use scopes because otherwise the datacontext will remain alive for a while... and it it really bad, you will have lots of datacontext and will never dispose them

Comment: Why would it not be disposed at the end of a request?

Comment: I actually only have one dbcontext, but it's not being disposed it seems like

Comment: Ah, if you are in the asp.net project, better to use one instance for each request... so you can use InstancePerRequest...

Comment: Still no avail, something really exceptional seems to be happening with the lifetime of the context :/

Comment: The context was being used in an area I didn't expect in order to send Apple push notifications... This was added by a coworker and was not an Autofac or Entity Framework issue..